# Can I move files into just partly same named folder in Windows CMD automatically?

Tags: batch-file

I'd like to move files into partly similar folders automatically with Windows CMD batch.

First, there are several files like below.

```
29100.txt
29103.doc
30011.ppt
30013.txt
40100.xls
```

Second, each folder based on file names will be made and move to the each folder.

```
29100.txt -> move to \29100\29100.txt
29103.doc -> move to \29103\29103.doc
30011.ppt -> move to \30011\30011.ppt
30013.txt -> move to \30013\30013.txt
40100.xls -> move to \40100\40100.xls
```

Lastly, I'd like to move partly same named files to common named folder.

```
29100\29100.txt -> move to \291\29100.txt
29103\29103.doc -> move to \291\29103.doc
30011\30011.ppt -> move to \300\30011.ppt
30013\30013.txt -> move to \300\30013.txt
40100\40100.xls -> move to \400\40100.xls
```

So, I asked user on Superuser and replied like below and
I'm very poor with background knowledge. I'm sorry.
And It doesn't need to be made each folder name like Second explain
and just moved directly to common folder name like \291, \300, \400
I explained poorly sorry again.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%i in (*) do mkdir "%%~ni"
for %%i in (*) do move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
for /d %%i in (*) do (
  set "x=%%i"
  echo "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"
  ren "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"
)
```

```
Oh! I found the answer from other question and I modified little
```

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'Dir /b *.*^|findstr "^[0-9]" '
) do call :subr "%%F"
exit /b

:subr
set "file=%~n1"
set "fold=%file:~0,3%
if not exist "%fold%" md "%fold%"
move %1 "%fold%"
exit /b
```

```
I don't know exactly the meaning of the batch but it works perfectly for me. Thank you all!
```

Comment: Using cmd.exe alone, yes.. but you will need to write a bit of batch code to do so.  Something (aka YOUR code) will need to decide where strip the parent directory (like 99951->999) and move the files accordingly.  Nothing will do this "out of the box".  Although batch would be an option, I suggest attacking this problem from PowerShell.  It is indeed more difficult to learn but also a first class scripting language which batch (which I love) is not.

Comment: I collected from Superuser like this..

@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (*) do mkdir "%%~ni"

for %%i in (*) do move "%%~i" "%%~ni"

for /d %%i in (*) do (

  set "x=%%i"

  echo "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"

  ren "%%i" "!x:~0,3!"
)

Comment: That's a script someone sent to you in another very similar question. What kind of full attempts did you make to modify it for the different requirements? Edit the question with that info instead of just commenting, please.